# Continuity vs. Mapping open sets to open sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have a question and I have no idea how to solve this:
One problem in my Real Analysis text book says:

> Show that if $\ell$ is a nonzero linear functional on a normed vector space not necessarily continuous, then $\ell$ maps open sets into open sets.

Isn't it against the definition? I mean saying that $f$ is continuous is equivalent to say that it maps open sets into open sets, right?

Is there any mistake in this problem? Or is just me that I'm misreading something?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Continuity means the inverse image of an open set is open. This does not necessarily mean open sets are mapped to open sets, and conversely if open sets are mapped to open sets this does not imply continuity.

Comment: The special functions which map open sets to open sets are called open functions. They are not necessarily continuous.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is continuous and maps $(-10,10)$ to $[-1,1]$...

Comment: Constant functions are continuous and map open sets to singletons, which are not in general open, and are not open in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A continuous map does not necessarily take open sets to open sets: take, e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ . Then the open set $(-1,1)$ is sent to the non-open set $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 15):

A map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is *continuous* if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$.

Note that the definition of continuity is different from the statement "continuous is equivalent to say that it maps open sets into open sets". In fact, the constant map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=0$ is continuous but the image of any open set $U$ under $f$ is $\{0\}$ which is not open in $\Bbb R$.

A map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces such that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ whenever $U$ is open in $X$ is called an [open map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps). A famous example of a map that is open but not continuous is the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) $\lfloor-\rfloor:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$.

In summary, continuous maps are not necessarily open maps and open maps are not necessarily continuous. Your question asks to prove that a certain kind of map is *always* an open map. Do you have any ideas how to get started?