# Definition of continuous function in topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition

According to some notes, definition of continuous function is as below :

> **Definition 1.1 (Continuous Function)** A function $f:X→Y$ is said to be continuous if the inverse image of every open subset of $Y$ is open in $X$.

And therefore we can say a function $f:X→Y$ have continuous inverse if the image of every open subset of $X$ is open in $Y$.

Wouldn't be better if we define a function as continuous if it mapped every open set in $X$ to an open set in $Y$ (in other word ,exactly what we defined for continuous inverse) ?
What is technical reason beyond this definition ?

Comment: $f(x)=x^{2}$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to itself. What is the image of $\mathbb R$ under it?

Comment: This question appear often in SE, and had already be answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094706/why-aren-t-continuous-functions-defined-the-other-way-around/3095384#3095384 . I advise you to quickly search on SE before posting.

Answer (score 2):

No, it would not be better. For instance: under that definition no constant function from $\Bbb R$ into itself would be continuous (with respect to the usual topology). However, constant functions are the most continuous functions that exist.